# Powershell Timeout After two Seconds

Tags: powershell, timeout, uuid

I'm new to powershell. I read some lines on www.powershell.com. Now I need your help to solve a problem. I want to read the UUID from clients in the Network. Therefore I created a document "pcs.txt" where all PCs are stored.

```
$pc = Get-Content pcs.txt #Read content of file
$cred = Get-Credential “domain\user” 

for ($i=0; $i -lt $pc.length; $i++)     {

    $Result=test-connection -ComputerName $pc[$i] -Count 1 -Quiet
    If ($Result -eq 'True')
    { 
        $uuid = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct -ComputerName $pc[$i] -Credential $cred).UUID 
        $Ausgabe=$pc[$i] + ';'+$uuid
        $Ausgabe  


    } 
    else
    {

        $Ausgabe=$pc[$i] + '; UUID nicht erhalten'
        $Ausgabe 
    }

}
```

First I test if the ping works. When the ping works I try to get the uuid.
Sometimes I don't get the uuid even if the ping worked. So I would like to code a timeout, which say -> go to next pc when you don't have the uuid after 2 seconds.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good workaround!

http://theolddogscriptingblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/wmi-hangs-and-how-to-avoid-them/

Here my working code:

```
$pc = Get-Content pcs.txt #FILE FROM THE HARDDISK
$cred = Get-Credential “DOMAIN\USER” #

for ($i=0; $i -lt $pc.length; $i++) 
{
$Result=test-connection -ComputerName $pc[$i] -Count 1 -Quiet 
If ($Result -eq 'True')
{ 
    $WMIJob = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct -ComputerName $pc[$i] -Credential $cred -AsJob     
    $Timeout=Wait-Job -ID $WMIJob.ID -Timeout 1 # the Job times out after 1 seconds.   
    $uuid = Receive-Job $WMIJob.ID

    if ($uuid -ne $null)
    {
        $Wert =$uuid.UUID 
        $Ausgabe=$pc[$i] + ';'+$Wert
        $Ausgabe  
    }

    else
    {
    <#$b = $error | select Exception       
    $E = $b -split (:)     
    $x = $E[1]   
    $Error.Clear()      #>
    $Ausgabe=$pc[$i] + '; got no uuid'
    $Ausgabe 
    }



} 
else
{
    $Ausgabe='PC not reached through ping.'
    $Ausgabe 
}


}
```

I hope I can help somebody with that

Answer (score 0):

Alas, there is no timeout parameter for `Get-WmiObject` commandlet. There is a feature request in [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/645165/add-timeout-parameter-to-get-wmiobject), but it is from 2011 and still open.

[A workaround](http://www.muscetta.com/2009/05/27/get-wmicustom/), which I haven't tested is available by using `System.Management`. I'll copy-and-paste it here in case the link goes dead. (And I hate SO answers that only contain links to resouces that may or may not exist...)

```
Function Get-WmiCustom([string]$computername,[string]$namespace,[string]$class,[int]$timeout=15){
$ConnectionOptions = new-object System.Management.ConnectionOptions
$EnumerationOptions = new-object System.Management.EnumerationOptions 

$timeoutseconds = new-timespan -seconds $timeout
$EnumerationOptions.set_timeout($timeoutseconds) 

$assembledpath = "\\" + $computername + "\" + $namespace
#write-host $assembledpath -foregroundcolor yellow 

$Scope = new-object System.Management.ManagementScope $assembledpath, $ConnectionOptions
$Scope.Connect() 

$querystring = "SELECT * FROM " + $class
#write-host $querystring 

$query = new-object System.Management.ObjectQuery $querystring
$searcher = new-object System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher
$searcher.set_options($EnumerationOptions)
$searcher.Query = $querystring
$searcher.Scope = $Scope 

trap { $_ } $result = $searcher.get() 

return $result
}
```

Comment: The Link is great. But I don't get it work
Alwais it raises an Exception connect with 0 arguments and get with 0 arguments.
$uuid = (Get-WmiCustom -computername $pc[$i] -namespace "root\cimv2" -class Win32_ComputerSystemProduct    -timeout 1).UUID